# Does code written in .innerHTML improve performance?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I have a section with sizeable MathJax content which gets displayed with a button onclick function. Two options to display:

```
onClick(){
  document.getElementById('section').style.display = 'inline';
}

onClick2(){
  document.getElementById('section').innerHTML = '[entire section code]'
}
```

Will the `.innerHTML` variant comparatively improve page loading speed? If so, is there a way to 'call' the entire section code inside the function instead of typing it out following `.innerHTML =` ?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: `Will the .innerHTML variant comparatively improve page loading speed?` I very much doubt it. But you can always do a performance test to confirm.

Comment: It also depends much on the structure of the data that you intend to integrate. If it requires translating everything from any type of objects to plaintext you'd most likely take a performance hit. Also relying on innerHTML can make things really hard to maintain.

Comment: @Robidu Not really. You'll take a hit no matter what. Even if the new value is exactly the same as the old value.

Comment: @Scott Marcus: So an assignment to `.innerHTML` deconstructs the DOM subtree in that spot no matter what?

Comment: @Robidu Yes. `.innerHTML` isn't a magic thing. It's just assigning a value to a property. No matter what value you set, you are still setting a new value into that property.

Comment: @Robidu I noticed that in your profile you wrote, *I code pages in XHTML (you cannot produce tag soup and still have it displayed). When that renders, you know that the document is syntactically correct.* and just wanted to let you know that this is not correct. Browsers do not validate HTML and browsers have no understanding of XHTML. Invalid HTML (or XHTML) will still render and often it will render visually correctly.

Comment: This may be OT, but o.k... Then you need to explain to me why obviously incorrect XHTML either produces an error or causes the browser to abort parsing the document (depends on the browser) if it's served with **application/xhtml+xml**. I don't know what type of browser you may be using, but mine refuses to render XHTML that violates the XML spec and instead throws an error message at me.

Comment: @Robidu There is a big difference between writing XHTML and serving XHTML. Writing XHTML (which is what you talk about in your profile) and parsing that under the default MIME type is what I'm referring to. A browser has no idea what XHTML is, it knows HTML and it knows XML, but not XHTML. So, when you write XHTML and serve it as normal, it's parsed as HTML. Now, you don't mention anything about serving your page with `application/xhtml+xml` (which is rarely done these days) and that would cause the XML parser to kick in, but ask yourself this question...

Comment: @Robidu ... What benefit is there to going to the trouble to write XHTML and serve it with `application/xhtml+xml` in the first place, unless you will have a need to treat the HTML as XML at some future point (highly unlikely)? It's a bunch of additional work for you and the browser with no discernible benefit. Just write your HTML in any modern editor that will alert to you validation errors as you type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ***Will the .innerHTML variant comparatively improve page loading speed?***

**Most certainly not.** It will decrease performance because the HTML parser will have to rebuild the DOM tree. `.innerHTML` can also potentially open up security holes and it will wipe out any event handlers that have been previously registered on the elements that are being replaced.

Modifications to the CSS will result in page re-paint operations and, depending on what the CSS is doing to the element(s), re-flows may be triggered as well. But, there are steps you can take to minimize these operations and the use of `.innerHTML` would cause these in addition to re-parsing the DOM.

**From [MDN on .innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):**

> **Value**
>
> A DOMString containing the HTML serialization of the element's
> descendants. Setting the value of innerHTML removes all of the
> element's descendants and replaces them with nodes constructed by
> parsing the HTML given in the string htmlString.